# OpenMP: having a complete 'for' loop into each thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have this code:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  #pragma omp single
  {
    for (int i=0; i<given_number; ++i) myBuffer_1[i] = myObject_1->myFunction();
  }

  #pragma omp single
  {
    for (int i=0; i<given_number; ++i) myBuffer_2[i] = myObject_2->myFunction();
  }
}

// and so on... up to 5 or 6 of myObject_x

// Then I sum up the buffers and do something with them
float result;
for (int i=0; i<given_number; ++i)
  result = myBuffer_1[i] + myBuffer_2[i];

// do something with result
```

If I run this code, I get what I expect but the CPU usage looks quite high. Instead, if I run it normally without OpenMP I get the same results but the CPU usage is much lower, despite running in a single thread.

I don't want to specify a number of threads, I wish the program pick the max number of threads according to the CPU capabilities, but I want that each `for` loop runs entirely in its own thread. How can I do that?

Also, my expectation is that the `for` loop for myBuffer_1 runs a thread, the other `for` loop runs another thread, and the rest runs in the 'master' thread. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

1. `#pragma omp single` has an implicit barrier at the end, you need to use `#pragma omp single nowait` if you want the two `single` block run concurrently.
2. However, for your requirement, using `section` might be a better idea

   ```
   #pragma omp parallel
   {
       #pragma omp sections 
       {
           #pragma omp section 
           {
               for (int i=0; i<given_number; ++i) myBuffer_1[i] = myObject_1->myFunction();  
           }
           #pragma omp section
           {
               for (int i=0; i<given_number; ++i) myBuffer_2[i] = myObject_2->myFunction();  
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: I tried with `sections` before trying `single`, and I also tried using `nowait`, I always get the same result: my program runs 17 threads, 7 of them take about 12,50 % of total CPU even when the processing is "idle". The CPU is an i7 (8 threads).

Comment: Post a minimal runnable test case, the bug must be somewhere else.

Comment: I have edited the example code in my post because the `for` loop that sums the buffers must be executed in the main thread. Btw, the functions `myFunction()` of `myObject_x` just do a series of very complex calculations and return a number, I don't think the problem is in there because they run fine without OpenMP. It's just that I don't know how to have each `for` loop run in its own thread in parallel.

Comment: How do you measure CPU, per-core or the total ? OpenMP attempts to use all CPU, for a 8 core CPU, each will take 12.5 % of your total CPU, which is the number you get. Serial code only use 1 core, so one core will use 12.5% of your total CPU, the rest are 0%.

Comment: 7 of the 8 threads take 12,50% each (which is exactly 100/8), so I suppose that each thread is working at its max load even when the processing is in idle (no data to be processed), and this looks weird to me.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the bugs are in OpenMP.