# Linux on quad core: single executable, 4 processes

Tags: linux, multithreading, c++11, fork

I have 4 executables that do some very complex tasks, each of these programs alone might take nearly 100% of the power of a single core of a quad core CPU, thus resulting in almost 25% of total CPU power. Since all of these programs use hardware resources that can't be shared between mutiple processes, I wish to run a single executable that spawns 3 child processes which, in turn, occupy the other three cores. I'm on Linux and I'm using C++11. Most of the complex code is running in its own class and the hardest part runs in a function that I usually call `Process()`, so I have 4 objects, each with its own `Process()` that, when running, takes 100% of a single core.

I tried using OpenMP but I don't think it's the best solution as I have no control over CPU affinity. Also using `std::thread` is not a good idea, because threads inherit the main process' CPU affinity. In Linux I think I can do this with fork() but I have no idea how the whole structure is made.

This might be related to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877420/openmp-having-a-complete-for-loop-into-each-thread) that was partly left unanswered, maybe because I was trying the wrong approach that works in some cases but not in my case.

An example of pseudo-code could be this:

```
int main()
{
  // ...init everything...

  // This alone takes 100% of a single core
  float out1 = object1->Process(); 

  // This should be spawned as a child process running on another core
  float out2 = object2->Process();

  // on another core...
  float out3 ...

  // yet another core...
  float out4 ...

  // This should still run in the parent process
  float total_output = out1 + out2 + out3 + out4;
}
```

Comment: I believe you could still use `std::thread` by calling `gettid()` from within that thread and then passing that as the `pid` parameter to `sched_setaffinity()`. Edit: actually, you don't even need to call `gettid()`, just leave `pid` zero and `sched_setaffinity()` will modify the *calling thread*'s affinity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::thread`, that's a front-end to `pthread_create()`. 
Then set its affinity with `sched_setaffinity()` from the thread itself as well.

As you asked, here a working stub:

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <thread>
#include <list>

void thread_func(int cpu_index) {
  cpu_set_t cpuSet;
  CPU_ZERO(&cpuSet);
  CPU_SET(cpu_index, &cpuSet);
  sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof( cpu_set_t), &cpuSet);
  /* the rest of the thread body here */
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)  {
  if (argc != 2) exit(1);
  int n_cpus = atoi(argv[1]);

  list< shared_ptr< thread > > lot;
  for (int i=0; i<n_cpus; ++i) {
    lot.push_back( shared_ptr<thread>(new thread(thread_func, i)));
  }

  for(auto tptr = lot.begin(); tptr != lot.end(); ++tptr) {
    (*tptr)->join();
  }
}
```

Note that for optimal behaviour it's important that each thread initialises its memory (that is, constructs its objects) in the thread body, if you want that your code is optimized also on multi-processors, because in case you are working on a NUMA system, memory pages are allocated on memory close to the CPU using them.

For example you can have a look to [this blog](http://stephen-tu.blogspot.it/2013/04/on-importance-of-numa-aware-memory.html).

However this is not an issue in your specific case, since your are dealing with a single processor system, or more specifically a system with just one numa node (many current AMD processors do contain two numa nodes, even if within a single physical package), and all the memory banks are attached there.

The final effect of using `sched_setaffinity()` in this context will be just to pin down each thread to a specific core.

Comment: Precisely, I am working on a quad core Cortex A9 ARMv7 CPU, it's an embedded Linux platform.

Comment: OK, I think it's not an SMP for sure then! The information I've reported applies to all AMD SMPs and MIPS SMPs and to Intel SMPs from when they abandoned their Front Side Bus (FSB).

Comment: So, do you think will it work with `std::thread` and `sched_setaffinity()`? Could you provide some example code that I can test?

Comment: do you have any third-party limitation ? Have you looked into https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm - Intel tbb ?

Comment: A single processor ARM processor definitely is SMP! (So is MIPS and x86) Multi processors are only common in larger servers and the OS takes care to minimize the overhead - initializing memory somewhere and then using it exclusively on another thread later will be completely negligible.

Comment: I guess the confusion here stems from the fact that HT is also used as a interconnect for multiple processors and what a CPU is. CPU and core are synonymous. Basically one processor has multiple CPUs that have one or more execution contexts (hardware threads if you want)

Comment: I agree, that I have used "SMP" in place of "multiple socket system" - my mistake, I'll edit the answer. But the fact that it's "completely negligible" using the "near memory" instead of the "far memory" holds true only in case your code use only cached data. In case of frequent memory accesses - that's what happens for most of the CPU intensive applications - you can see the difference because of the increased latency in the memory accesses, that in some cases can be dramatic.

Comment: @MarkMiles Given your platform you have only one numa node for sure, you do not need to check for affinity, since all memory is accessed equally by all the cores. I'll add the code and fix the answer later for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to program anything.  The command [`taskset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) changes the CPU affinity of a currently running process or creates and sets it for a new process.

Running a single executable that spawns other programs is no different than executing the programs directly, except for the common initialization implied by the comments in your stub.

```
taskset 1 program_for_cpu_0 arg1 arg2 arg3...
taskset 2 program_for_cpu_1 arg1 arg2 arg3...
taskset 4 program_for_cpu_2 arg1 arg2 arg3...
taskset 8 program_for_cpu_3 arg1 arg2 arg3...
```

I am suspicious of setting CPU affinities.  I have yet to find an actual use for doing so (other than satisfying some inner need for control).

Unless the CPUs are not identical in some way, there should be no need to restrict a process to a particular CPU.

1. The Linux kernel normally keeps a process on the same CPU unless it enters an extended wait for i/o, a semaphore, etc.
2. Switching   a process from one CPU to another does not incur any particular overhead except in NUMA configurations with local memory per CPU.  AFAIK, ARM implementations do not do that.
3. If a process should   exhibit non-CPU bound behavior, allowing the kernel scheduler flexibility to reassign a process to a now-available CPU should improve system performance.  Processes bound to a CPU cannot participate in resource availability.

Comment: 1. Or another process needs to be executed and than it can happens that threads start dancing over cores. 2. Except that cache lines are left behind in the old core, even if cores are within the same processor, and so switching cores result in expensive and useless cache misses. That's the ultimate reason for which current kernels try to enforce thread-core affinity. 3. I agree that you loose flexibility, but it happens all the times you optimise, as the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Sigismondo:  good point about caching, but on multi-core ARMs, level0 cache is unified.  None of the systems I have worked on have level1 or greater caches.

Comment: is level0 the ARM name for L2? I'm not expert with ARM yet :) however L1 is local to cores - or am I getting it wrong? http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a9.php for example